# Extracting and comparing digits in specific position in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I compare several pieces of data to be able to find string differences in the last two characters before a symbol of the data?

So if I had emails for instance, and wanted to pull only incidences where there was a 1 character difference between two emails in the last two characters before '@' only if there were created a day within each other. So -

i.e

```
samfake@gmail.com              2018-09-01
johnslife@googlio.com          2018-09-20
samfake1@gmail.com             2018-09-02
sarahshouse@yahoo.com          2018-08-01
sarahshouse4@yahoo.com         2018-08-01
samfake4@gmail.com             2018-08-02
notgoing@hotmail.com           2016-02-04
notgoing3@hotmail.com          2018-05-04
```

and I wanted to see something where I could pull these emails:

```
samfake@gmail.com
samfake1@gmail.com
sarahshouse@yahoo.com
sarahshouse4@yahoo.com
samfake4@gmail.com
```

Where the last digits before the '@' sign differ by 1, in comparison to at least 1 other email given that the compared data is within a day of each other. It would be great to specify a condition where the remainder of the email has to remain the same during these comparisons within SQL. So the only place the character difference = 1 would be the last digits before '@'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'samfake@gmail.com' email, DATE '2018-09-01' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'johnslife@googlio.com', '2018-09-20' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'samfake1@gmail.com', '2018-09-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sarahshouse@yahoo.com', '2018-08-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sarahshouse4@yahoo.com', '2018-08-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'samfake4@gmail.com', '2018-08-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'notgoing@hotmail.com', '2016-02-04' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'notgoing3@hotmail.com', '2018-05-04' 
), temp AS (
  SELECT domain,
    ARRAY_AGG(user) OVER(PARTITION BY domain ORDER BY day 
    RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) users
  FROM (
    SELECT UNIX_DATE(dt) day, 
      SUBSTR(email, STRPOS(email, '@')) domain,
      SUBSTR(email, 1, STRPOS(email, '@') - 1) user
    FROM `project.dataset.table`  
  )
)
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(user, domain) email
FROM temp, UNNEST(
  (SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG([user1, user2]) 
    FROM UNNEST(users) user1, UNNEST(users) user2 
    WHERE user1 > user2
    AND (user1 = SUBSTR(user2, 1, LENGTH(user2) - 1)
    OR user2 = SUBSTR(user1, 1, LENGTH(user1) - 1))
  )
) user
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(users) > 1
```

with result

```
Row email    
1   samfake1@gmail.com   
2   samfake@gmail.com    
3   sarahshouse4@yahoo.com   
4   sarahshouse@yahoo.com
```

> Update to address > Quick question, my date is a timestamp type

use `UNIX_DATE(DATE(dt))` then

Comment: Brilliant. Quick question, my date is a timestamp type, and I get returned this error `No matching signature for function UNIX_DATE for argument types: TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: UNIX_DATE(DATE)` for line 16.

Comment: Also, I would need `samefake4@gmail.com` to show up as well?

Comment: it does not fit into your one-day criteria! please clarify!

Comment: any clarification about samefake4@gmail.com? base on one day rule - it should not be in the result

Comment: all good! thanks for checking up @mikhail - I was mistaken. Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

co-related sub-query, one  approximate approach in case of unique name

```
select * from t
where exists ( select 1 from t t1 where t1.email like '%'+t.email+'%'
              and t1.date=t.date)
```